# TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
#-*- coding: cp857 -*-

from tkinter import *

###########################################################

root=Tk()

root.title("MY FILM ARCHIVE")

root.resizable(False, False)

########################################################### 


def add():
    db = open(r"C:\Users\PC\Desktop\db.txt", "a+")
    enter=input("Enter your's film: "),
    db.write(enter + "\n")
    db.close()
    db.flush()    

button=Button(text="Add Film!",command=add, font=("Flux",15, "bold"))
button.pack(expand="yes", anchor="center")

mainloop()
```

When I run this program and push the button I get the following error :(

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple
```

Comment: Please include the *full* traceback.

Answer (score 5):

That comma at the end of this line:

```
enter=input("Enter your's film: "),
```

Is making it equivalent to:

```
enter = (input("Enter your's film: "),)
```

Which stores a one-tuple in `enter`. Remove the comma and it'll work.